# Chrome extension switch tabs queue

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to queue tab switching and let the background script know when it is ok to process the next tab switch?

For example in `content.js`

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("Do something", function(resp) { 
   doSomethingFor3Seocnds().then(function(resp) { 
    // now it's OK to go to the next tab
 })
}
```

`background.js`

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
  chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {"active": true}, function(tab){
    // only run if OK to go to next tab
    return sendResponse(tab)
  });
});
```

Comment: There's no API to delay switching. You can try switching to the previous tab immediately, but I'm afraid it'll flicker. If that's not what you meant, I don't think I understand the question as it seems too obvious - you can always send another (special) message when it's ok to switch.

Comment: Also, your listener is missing "return true", see [Chrome Extension Message passing: response not sent](//stackoverflow.com/a/20077854)

Comment: @wOxxOm so i can return a message that let's that let's the background script know when it's ok to switch?

Comment: Yes that's my point. Why not? Right now I'm not sure what the problem is besides the missing "return true".

Comment: @wOxxOm how does the background script know when the content script is done with it's operation? how does it get that data? My understanding is that `return true` gets you the data in the content script from the background script

Comment: 1) there are multiple ways depending on what you mean by "know" and "operation" 2) `return true` is required for asynchronous response as explained in the linked answer.